# Keras ValueError: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (2592, 1) Python3

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am having an issue when trying to train my model in Keras 2.0.8, Python 3.6.1, and a Tensorflow Backend.

Error Message:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (2592, 1)

```
X_train = numpy.swapaxes(X_train, 1, 3)
X_test = numpy.swapaxes(X_test, 1, 3)

print("X_train shape: ") --> size = (2592, 1, 1366, 96)
print("-----")
print("X_test shape") --> size = (648, 1, 1366, 96)
print("-----")
print(Y_train.shape) --> size = (2592,)
print("-----")
print("Y_test shape") --> size = (648,)
```

Relevant Code snippets:

```
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')

def create_model(weights_path=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=(1, 1366, 96)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', dim_ordering="th"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)
    return model

model = create_model()
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
      batch_size=32,
      epochs=100,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

**Line 142, where I call model.fit() is where I am getting this error**

**Things I have tried to fix this error**
Referenced these stack overflow posts:

I tried to reshape the Y_test and Y_train numpy arrays using the following code:

```
Y_train.reshape(2592, 2)
Y_test.reshape(648, 2)
```

However, I get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2592 into shape (2592,2)

Comment: Your MCVE is almost complete. Which line is throwing the error? Also there's 1336 vs 1366 in the error; make sure you copy the message verbatim.

Comment: Line 142, which is when I call model.fit() I updated the question.

Comment: OK, the number mismatch comes from your code: `input_shape` has a wrong value in `Conv2D`. I suggest passing the shape of the inputs explicitly to `create_model` rather than hard-coding it. Magic numbers like this are prone to errors.

Comment: Sorry, it appears that was a typo when I was writing the code. After fixing the `input shape` in `Conv2D` I get the error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (2592, 1). I will update the question.

Comment: The new error is clear. Why are you trying to reshape from N elements to N*2 elements? What is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: You need to understand the underlying meaning of your first error and do it right rather than trying to force random arrays to an arbitrary shape.

Comment: I got the error that dense_4 expected input in format (None, 2), and since my input was currently in (2592, 1), I decided to try and reshape so the 2nd dimension had length 2 (However I don't know if this is the correct approach).

Comment: Actually, I think the correct approach would be to make one-hot targets using np.eye. I got it working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the `categorical_crossentropy` loss, you have to use one-hot encoded labels. For this you can use the function `to_categorical` from `keras.utils.np_utils`

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train_onehot = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test_onehot = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
```

Then use the one-hot encoded labels to train your model.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me you need to change the last layer of the NN:

```
def create_model(weights_path=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=(1, 1366, 96)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', dim_ordering="th"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)
    return model
```

Comment: Is there more of an explanation for this, or is this just another arbitrary way to make the error go away?

Comment: @AndrasDeak sure there is, check the shape of your y data (labels), for example, Y_train.shape, the second dimension of the Y_train MUST be equal to the size of the last layer of the NN. Why? Simple, how should you network work if you have one label but the output layer hast two?

Comment: OK, I just wanted to make sure that there's deeper reasoning behind your answer (considering the lack of explanation). I don't know machine learning, I just saw that OP is prone to a bit of cargo culting, and wanted to make sure the answer is helpful ;)